# Trying to hie my profile avatar in learndash

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, learndash

i used this code to hide my avatar profile picture in learndash,why its not working

```
#learndash_profile .profile_info .profile_avatar {
    display: none;
}
```

help please

Comment: try `display: none !important;`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You should ask your question on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ where more people may know the answer.

Answer (score 1):

#ld-profile .ld-profile-avatar {display: none;}

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 1):

may be its overwrite with other CSS code, use

```css
#learndash_profile .profile_info .profile_avatar {
    display: none !important;
}
```